# How to encode correctly for Sabre OAuth API?

Tags: sabre

Based on Sabre documentation i need to encode with Base64 the clientId:password.
I did it and put it like per documentation:

```
Authorization: Basic valueBase64Encoded
```

But always gets an error

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Credentials are missing or the syntax is not correct"}
```

I believe i put values correct in Base64 from my account in Sabre with seperate colon.

```
clientId:password
```

Also, three x-www-form-urlencoded values are attached to POST : grant_type, username, password

Where is my mistake? Or what should i do here?
Thanks for a help

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode your clientId and your password first. Follow this steps:

1. Encode in Base64 this string `V1:{yourUsername}:{yourPCC}:AA`
2. Encode in Base64 your password
3. Encode in Base64 this {resultOfFirstStep}:{resultOfSecondStep}

The result of the third step should be your encode string

The body `grant_type=client_credentials` is correct

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are referring to [v3](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/session_management/token_create_api/v3) of the API, and Coti is referring to [v2](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/session_management/token_create_api/v2) in her answer. I have not had success with v3 yet, but v2 is working for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).